# upgrading xamarin breaks mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Just upgraded to the latest of Xamarin and now when I build my MvvmCross android app I get the following error:

(0,0): Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxBind' in package 'com.xxx' (yyy)

I am getting this error for every file where I am using the MvvmCross attributes: MvxBind and MvxItemTemplate

My MvvmCrossAttr.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!--<declare-styleable name="CustomFonts">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
  </declare-styleable>-->
  <declare-styleable name="MvxBinding">
    **<attr name="MvxBind" format="string"/>**
    <attr name="MvxLang" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxListView">
    <attr name="MvxItemTemplate" format="string"/>
    <attr name="MvxDropDownItemTemplate" format="string"/>
    <attr name="GroupItemTemplate" format="string"/>     
  </declare-styleable>
  <item type="id" name="MvxBindingTagUnique"/>
  <item type="id" name="MvxBindableListItemTagUnique"/>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxImageView">
    <attr name="MvxSource" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And this is how I am using it in a layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxx"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_search_property_button_border"
    android:clickable="true"
    local:MvxBind="Click NavigateToRestaurantCommand"
    android:padding="1dp">
...
```

This is very frustrating. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show how you are using it in your Layout files?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I have updated the question with what you asked.

Comment: If this was caused by a Xamarin update, then have you tried Xamarin support? You are paying them for this

Comment: I was going to. but thought maybe its something quick I missed. the problem is that a new MvvmCross project works...

Comment: Try and set it local ns to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto